# boost::interprocess memory allocator on anonymous segment

Tags: c++, linux, boost, multiprocessing, interprocess

I'm trying to use an mmap-like segment to allocate objects on stl containers, for that I'm using boost::interprocess which provides with memory mappings, allocators and anonymous memory mapping support.
A bit like [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map)

My problem is that the `anonymous_shared_memory` function [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.anonymous_shared_memory) returns something that looks half mapped file and half shared memory(makes sense with mmap :) ) and although both styles work with [interprocess allocators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html) this one looks like its missing a segment_manager which does the actual chunk allocation.
As it returns a high-level `mapped_region` already mapped in the process but with no manager and no way that I can see to hook in a `segment_manager`.

Comment: If `anonymous_shared_memory` does not conform to the protocol interprocess allocators expect, it sounds like a bug. I recommend you to try reporting it.

Answer (score 3):

A `mapped_region` is a low to mid-level object, and literally represents just the memory.  [Managed shared memory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_shared_memory.constructing_managed_shared_memories), however

> is an advanced class that combines a shared memory object and a mapped region that covers all the shared memory object,

so it is the managed memory that possess the `segment_manager`.

Given that you want to use `anonymous_shared_memory`, first you'd get the `memory_region` as per the example, then you would use placement `new` to put a `segment_manager` at [the beginning](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/architecture.html#interprocess.architecture.architecture_algorithm_to_managed.architecture_segment_manager) of it. Its [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/segment_manager.html#id815645-bb) takes the size of the memory segment that it is being constructed in.  I do not know if this includes the size of the manager, although I suspect it is included.

Comment: @Arkaitz, have you tried this? Would you like me to put together some code for it?

Comment: please do; it would be helpful!

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf it has been a _very_ long time since I looked at this, so if I don't post code this weekend for it, poke me again.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf I thought I recognized the unpronounceable name ... :)

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf not entirely sure what you are asking for.